# dpkg error code (100)

Tags: dpkg

Whenever I am trying to install anything using `apt-get`,  it shows:

```
Could not exec dpkg
Returned with error code (100)
```

Same result when I execute

```
apt-get upgrade
```

When I type

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

It tells me dpkg is not installed and when I run:

```
apt-get install dpkg
```

it tells it is the newest version, but when I run:

```
apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```

it again returns `error code (100)`

Even system updates are failing to occur, no software is getting downloaded even from the Software Download Center.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Check if dpkg is missing some libraries:

```
ldd /usr/bin/dpkg
```

If any library is missing, try to install it. If that's not the issue, then try the following:

```
sudo -i
mkdir /tmp/dpkg

cd /tmp/dpkg
```

#### If you are running a 32 bit version of ubuntu

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.2_i386.deb
```

#### For 64 bit

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb
ar x dpkg*.deb data.tar.gz
tar xfvz data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg
sudo cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```