# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100) could not exec dpkg

Tags: apt, dpkg

I have an error on Ubuntu 16.04 when I use

```
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Nagy I believe this is the same issue as here https://askubuntu.com/questions/901482/dpkg-error-code-100

Answer (score 4):

Go to this url http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/ 
and you will see a list of `dpkg` packages. You need to find the `dpkg` version you need than open new terminal.
Anywhere your machine I select Desktop.

```
mkdir dpkg 
cd dpkg
```

Run:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/
```

(Add the version of dpkg you need after the last `/`)

For example I needed `dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb` but this does not exist any more so I chose the closest one which is

```
dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb
```

So:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb
```

Run

```
ar x dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb
```

Now you can see the contents:

```
~/dpkg $ ls
control.tar.gz  data.tar.gz  debian-binary  dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb
```

Run

```
~/dpkg $ tar xfvz data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg
./usr/bin/dpkg
~/dpkg $ ls
control.tar.gz  data.tar.gz  debian-binary  dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb  usr
~/dpkg $ cd usr/bin/
~/dpkg/usr/bin $ ls
dpkg

~/dpkg/usr/bin $ sudo cp dpkg /usr/bin/
```

Then you can run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I hope that helps.