# How to resolve E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1), began throwing errors spontateously

Tags: apt, dpkg

I understand this question is commonly asked, but my case is different and the solutions to other similar situations do not work for me.
Whenever I try to do just about anything in apt (install, update, etc) I get the following message eventually:

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-oem-20.04d (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cloud-init
 libssl1.1:amd64
 linux-headers-5.15.0-71-generic
 tzdata
 tex-common
 texlive-latex-base
 texlive-latex-recommended
 texlive-binaries
 lmodern
 texlive-fonts-recommended
 libpam-systemd:amd64
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
 tipa
 openssl
 texlive-base
 tex-gyre
 linux-headers-5.15.0-72-generic
 libmysqlclient21:amd64
 libzip5:amd64
 texlive
 openssh-client
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
 openscad
 linux-generic-hwe-20.04
 linux-oem-20.04b
 linux-headers-oem-20.04d
 linux-oem-20.04d
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: You've provided the final **summary** detail, with the error message(s) provided earlier in the listing.. You should read the actual error message(s) to understand the issue, not just the repeated summary detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) - but how do I find the meaningful error messages in APT's output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166808/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-but-how-do-i-find-the)

Comment: I have edited the post to reflect more information. Thank you for the help

Comment: `df -h;df -i` and `dkms status`  and `dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|m|h|i]'` also `uname -r`  you have different kerneltrees on your system. Please add this to your question through [edit]

Comment: The issue has been resolved by the suggestion of this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t